# separate queries in mysql, db2 and oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, db2

to separate queries in an sql file:
with mysql :
we can use
 `Delimiter /`

example:

```
Delimiter /
select * from product;
/
select * from h_product;
/
Delimiter ;
insert into ptoduct(prod_name)values('my_prod_name');
```

and for oracle and db2? what to use? also Delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a DB2 CLP script you can use the SET TERMINATOR instruction to change the statement terminator "on the fly":

```
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
select * from sysibm.sysdummy1;

--#SET TERMINATOR /
create or replace trigger t1 ...
begin
 ...
end
/
```

You would then call this as `db2 -tf myscript.sql`. Note that the SET TERMINATOR instruction must be in upper case.

I don't think there is an option to customize terminators in the Oracle SQL*Plus scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle SQL*PLUS you use semicolon `;` as SQL terminator and `.` as PL/SQL block

terminator. Unlike sql terminator(`;`), which terminates and executes SQL statement,
PL/SQL block

terminator(`.`) only informs SQL*PLUS that the block has ended and left in the buffer for further editing

if such a need arises or execution using slash `/`.

You can change SQl terminator by issuing `SET SQLTERMINATOR ':'` (for example).

You can change PL/SQL block terminator by issuing `SET BLOCKTERMINATOR '!'`(for example).

To terminate and execute a PL/SQL block you use forward slash `/`.

Comment: as I understand, with oracle we add sqlterminator / select * from product;
/
select * from h_product;
/
sqlterminator ;
insert into ptoduct(prod_name)values('my_prod_name'); 
?

Comment: @neila To execute a DML statement it's enough to use just semicolon(`;`) (`select * from h_product; select * from product;`). If you omit semicolon you can use slash on the next line. Either of those approaches will terminate and execute DML statement.

Comment: I tried SET SQLTERMINATOR '/' for oracle and that's ok :)
thx

Answer (score 1):

In DB2 you use `;` as SQL terminator (for SQL PL and PL/SQL).

You define the statement termination character with the td option.

For example, to execute multiple SQL, you call db2 like this:

```
db2 -tf script.sql
```

*script.sql*

```
create table t1 (c1 int);
create table 
  t2 (c2 int);
```

When executing a script that contains Stored procedures, triggers or functions, you can separate them with any character and define the statement termination character via the -td option. Most of the time @ is used.

```
db2 -td@ -f scriptSQLPL.sql
```

*scriptSQLPL.sql*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST ()
 RESULT SETS 1
 LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
 DECLARE value INT DEFAULT 1;

 SET value = 0;
END @
```

If you do not specify any statement termination character, every single line separated by a carriage return will be considered as a statement. However, you can put backslashes in order to execute multilines statements

```
db2

create \
table \
t1 \
( col1 int )
```

In the last example, Interactive mode was used instead of using a file.